# Poissons probability distribution

Tags: poisson-distribution, poissons-equation

At a specified point on a bicycle path, bicycles are assumed to arrive according to a Poisson probability
distribution. Bicycles are counted in 15-second intervals for a period of 30 minutes (a total of 120 intervals).It is noted that no bicycles arrived in 16 of those 120 intervals.

a) What is the expected number of bicycles in any one-minute period?

b) What is the average volume, in vehicles per hour?

c) How many of these 120 intervals have exactly three bicycles arriving.

So, I have started with the main formula p(x) = (e^(-qt) * qt^x) / x! with time interval = 1 min, also I have calculated that bicycles appeared only in 86 % (120 - 16 = 104 ; 104*100/120 = 0.86)

Can somebody help me to start?

Comment: Matching the probability that zero bicycles arrive in 15 second using the Poisson formulae to the 16/120 intervals will give you a value for $q$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will try now